# Which of these line of code is "better,” and why?

Tags: php

**First:**

```
 protected function isValid($orderIds)
 {
     ......

     $orderCount = Some Calculation... ; 

     return ( $orderCount == count($orderIds) );
 }
```

**Second:**

```
 protected function isValid($orderIds)
 {
     ......

     $orderCount = Some Calculation... ; 

     return ( $orderCount == count($orderIds) ) ? 1 : 0;
 }
```

I am using this function like this

```
......

$isValid = $this->isValid($orderIds);
if($isValid) {
   // do some thing here
}
```

Please look above written code. Is anything wrong, if I choose first function over second function?

Comment: Don't know why people are Downvoating my question

Comment: I removed the invalid CakePHP tag. In general: You should focus on other things than nano opt or subjectiv code style topics for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method will only return the type boolean & in the second method, you are just adding overhead to return `1 or 0`. If you only need to check if the method has successfully done its job then I recommend to you go with the first approach.

Comment: May I add that "isValid" certainly calls for a boolean value.